# VBS InputBox hidden behind other windows

Tags: vbscript, focus, inputbox

In a script I'm currently working on, I'm building a dynamic list of items and need to get user's feedback on which one to load.
Currently using the *InputBox* method, which works flawlessly, but very often gets hidden behind other windows on the user's screen.

I'm looking for a way to bring it to the front, similar effect as *vbSystemModal* for *MsgBox*.

Most answers I found (on this site and others) deal with VB.Net and commands / subroutines which don't apply to a VBS like I'm using. Other similar questions on VBS I found did not get any concrete answers or were closed with suggestions to use a different scripting language...

I am planing to move to a HTA in a future release of this script. This should offer me many alternatives to such issues. But for now, I don't have the time for a complete rebuild of the script and need to get working what I have.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction with the input box focus or any other creative alternative your combined wisdom can conjur up!

Kind regards!

Comment: A program has 2 seconds to put a window up. If it doesn't it loses the ability to make itself the foreground window. This is to stop programs stealing focus.

Comment: There are 9 rules (of which 2 seconds is most likely). You have to meet one of them to set the foreground window. They are detailed here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: @Noodles: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to tell me and what that means for my VBS script. I'm looking for a way to explicitly give the focus to the InputBox pop-up window. Are you saying that the inputBox must be spawned within the first two seconds of script runtime to be given the focus?

Comment: YES I AM. Although there vare 9 rules of which ONE must be met. You need to design your program to meet one of them.

Comment: Try something like putting up `wscript.Shell.Popup` which can be set to popup and self close after 1 sec as the first thing in your script.

Comment: Re above. That will give you the foreground window. It depends what happens after it closes - but if you don't click anywhere your inputbox may work.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the AutoItX.dll, which you can downland from here: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/

Then use WinSetOnTop:

```
Set oAutoIt = WScript.CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
oAutoIt.WinSetOnTop "MyInputBoxName", "", 1
```

or to set focus only use WinActivate:

```
Set oAutoIt = WScript.CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
oAutoIt.WinActivate "MyInputBoxName", ""
```

By the way: years ago I started with VBS, then I added the AutoItX control and wrote also some things in HTA. But finally I changed to the full AutoIt app.

Comment: That sets a window's Z order. It does NOT set the foreground window. The foreground window has keyboard focus.

Comment: "That ..." What? Try it!

Comment: You are setting the ontop attribute. That does not set the foreground window. Keyboard goes to the foreground window.